# How to set chef recipe to install chef gems only after certain steps

Tags: rubygems, chef-infra, chef-recipe, recipe

Am running a chef recipe and it's trying to install gems first later linking a directory. But I want first to link a directory then install gems as all the gems are located in a directory which I want to link up to my specific directory. Is it possible? If possible how can I make it.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably mean is that you're installing the gem at compile-time but the `link` resource is set to run normally at converge-time. Check out https://coderanger.net/two-pass/ for a more detailed explanation of the two pass process. But in this case you probably want to change your code so the `link` resource runs at compile-time:

```
link ... do
  ...
  action :nothing
end.run_action(:create)
```